# Is there another name or site for this "Dominotion" puzzle?

Tags: puzzle-identification, dominoes

I discovered this very old Javascript game in my old bookmarks.
It's a great puzzle.

http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/Games/dominotion.html

Does anyone know another name for this puzzle or a site or app where one can play it?

---

Edit: @Emrakul added some great information, in particular, the generally known name for it, which allows googling.

Now, the great thing about the version I linked above is that:

1. it allows you to mark the edges which outline the dominoes individually, and
2. it also keeps track of the number of adjacent instances of each number pair.

In other words, this is much better than the versions I have found given the name "Dominosa" because you can keep track of the incremental partial solutions and you don't waste all the time searching the puzzle grid manually.

Any additional leads on an app version with this support? (Or any volunteers :)  )

Comment: Thanks for bringing that type of puzzle to my attention.

Comment: Adding additional follow-on question

Answer (score 6):

This puzzle appears to originate in many places, primarily under the name "Dominosa." I can't seem to find anything called "Dominotion" on the web besides on the UCLA website. (It's not actually a name I've heard before for this puzzle.)

One of the oldest reference I can find online comes from [Simon Tatham's puzzle collection](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/), for which there is a working JS version [on his website](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/dominosa.html). You can also download an executable version from the same (or by following [this direct download link](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/dominosa.exe)).

Additionally, a search for "dominosa" on pretty much any platform will return results - for instance, [Dominosa](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oxothuk.dominosa) on Google Play.

Comment: Exactly 4000 rep Emrakul O_O

Comment: @warspyking Muahaha! I am now a Trusted Use--wait

Comment: Haha funny. I got there recently, it took me like 150 consecutive days in a row since join, but I made it lol.

Comment: See follow up in OQ.